# Exporting Windows Resource Monitor Data with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

**Problem Definition:** We have done some configuration level changes in our web server which is basically a IIS server. We have increased number of threads from default 300 to somewhat 450.

And this changes might crash our server.

So we want to monitor the worker threads and we want to log this to a database periodically.

**My Progress So far:**

So far I was able to get details with one exe running with below mentioned Powershell command.

(Just replace w3wp.exe with any processes name to get result)

```
$name = "w3wp.exe" 
$processHandle = (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = '$name'").ProcessId
$Threads = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Thread -Filter "ProcessHandle = $processHandle"
$threads | Select-Object priority, thread*, User*Time, kernel*Time |
Out-GridView -Title "The $name process has $($threads.count) threads"
```

**Issue:** In above mentioned PowerShell script it is not able to give me result for exes when w3wp.exe is running with multiple PIDs.

Is there a way we can get result for multiple running exes?

Table should be of

Processor name| PID| Worker Name| No. of Threads|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I got an error running your code which I would have expected you to get as well

> ```
>  Get-CimInstance : Invalid query 
>  At line:3 char:12
>  + $Threads = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Thread -Filter "ProcessHandle ...
>  +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041017,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
> ```

Which makes sense since the `-Filter` would look like this... as it did for me using chrome.exe as a test. Which is not valid.

```
ProcessHandle = 7224 7420 8688 8800 8916 460 10884 7340 10956 6756 14604 13260 9588 18020 22264 11516 17684 12664
```

So I just added in a loop to allow for multiple `$processHandle`s and it seems to be working fine.

```
$Threads = $processHandle | Foreach-Object{
    Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Thread -Filter "ProcessHandle = $_"
}
```